# Meeting of Sri Krishnaprema and Sri Ramana Maharshi

Tags: krishna-prem

I read about the meeting of two great saints : Sri Ramana Maharshi and Sri Krishnaprema. Sri Maharshi was in tears seeing the idol of Sri Krishna that Sri Krishnaprema worshipped.It is a rare incident where a greatest Jnani met a greatest bhakta.

Could someone narrate the beautiful incident? I read about it in abook written by the renowned scholar late Dr.Govindagopal Mukhopadhyay.

Comment: Thats interesting. Never heard about Sri Krishnaprema.But Sri Ramana Maharishi is one of few Advaitins for whom I have deep respect ..as practice of self enquiry really changed my life. I would like to know about this incident too...

Comment: Both are unique characters btw

Comment: i agree. Though I don't know much Krishnaprem ..wiki article seems quite informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In 1948, four years after his Guru left her body, Krishnaprem, a **siddha** Gaudiya Vaishnava (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna_Prem) traveled to South India to visit the illumined sage Sri Ramana Maharshi (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramana_Maharshi)  He repected Sri Ramana Maharshi very much. As late Dr.Govindagopal Mukhopadhyay writes in hisn'Mahajan-Samvad, Sri Krishnaprem always carried a deity of Radha and Krishna with Him and regularly worshipped them.When Maharshi saw these idols, He shed tears in divine ecstacy.It  remindes me the famous sloka of Srimad-Bhagavatam (1/7/10):

> AtmArAmAscha munayor nirgranthA api urukrame|kurvanti ahaitukim bhaktim itthambhutaguno harih|| meaning that the seers who are always immersed in the bliss of the Self and not bound any more by injunctions of any scriptures are devoted to Sri Hari without an iota of desire.They can not help being devoted to Sri Hari as He is the abode of so many  beautiful qualities.

**We get the detailed description of the meeting of these two saints in Krishnaprem's own words as narrated to his friend and another very renowned person late Dilip kumar Ray. Its really a remarkable meeting and each word is important,So I present without any edit. I apologige for this long quotation but am sure that many readers will enjoy each and every word of Krishnaprem.**

> "How profound is my admiration and veneration for the Sage. I agree wholeheartedly with Sri Aurobindo's verdict that his tapasya is a shining light of India. So I went to Ramana Ashram in Tiruvannamalai to receive his blessing.
>
> "When, in the evening, I entered the hall where the Maharshi reclines daily on his couch, I sat down in silence along with the others, to meditate at his feet. But believe it or not, as soon as I sat down I heard a voice questioning me over and over again: 'Who are you? Who are you? Who are you?' I tried hard to ignore it, but it went on and on like an importunate visitor, knocking at the door, who insisted on being admitted. So, in the end, I just had to formulate an answer: 'I am Krishna's servant.' At once the question changed, like a shape-changer, into: 'Who is Krishna?' I answered: 'Nanda's son.' No use. The question was repeated relentlessly. I thought up other answers, like, 'He's an Avatar, the One-in-all, the Resident of every heart' and so on, but the questioning would not cease, till at last I gave it up, left the hall and returned, deeply disturbed, to meditate. I had no peace. The voice gave me no respite, till, in the end, I had to evoke Radharani [Lord Krishna's consort] who asked me very simply what answers I had given. I told Her but She shook Her head and then, at last, revealed it to me.
>
> He anticipated me, holding up his hand.
>
> "No, Dilip, don't ask me, please! I won't tell you, for you will tell everybody. Don't I know you? But listen, for there is more.
>
> "Next morning," he went on, "when I sat down again at his blessed feet, the Maharshi suddenly gave me a lightning glance and smiled. I knew at once beyond the shadow of a doubt that he was the author of it all and that he also knew that I had divined his part correctly.
>
> "Then, as I closed my eyes to meditate, a deep peace descended into me and settled like a block of ice, as it were, till my every cell was numb with an exquisite bliss. Didn't you have the same experience, as I think you wrote to me once?
>
> "As I meditated," he went on, " it was borne home to me through the mystic silence that this peace stemmed ultimately from the Lord Himself. Doesn't He say in the Gita that He Himself is the primal source of all experience [Gita, IX. 18] 'I am the goal, the upholder, the lord, the witness, the abode, the refuge and the friend. (I am) the origin and the dissolution, the ground, the resting place and the imperishable seed.' The peace in this instance was transmitted through His beloved agent, the Maharshi.
>
> "But isn't that precisely why He sends to us as His deputies, the great saints and sages, Messiahs and Avatars?"
>
> "Of course He does. Didn't Ma [Yashoda Ma, Sri Krishnaprem's Guru] explain to you the import of His naralila - that is, why He comes down to us from age to age to play hide and seek with us, humans, as a human being?" He paused for a little, then gave me a quizzical look.
>
> "I feel tempted to tell you the sequel."
>
> "Only you have misgivings about confiding in me?" I finished for him, laughing.
>
> "Well, I'll risk it," he laughed back. "For what happened was too wonderful. So listen.
>
> "As I went on imbibing this delectable peace - meditating at his feet - I suddenly took it into my head to return the compliment and put a question to him in silence: 'And who are you, may I humbly ask?' It so happened that the next moment I had to open my eyes involuntarily when, lo, I found his couch empty!
>
> "There was the couch where he had presided two seconds before, but in the twinkling of an eye, as it were, he had vanished - just melted into thin air! I closed my eyes once more and then looked again, and there he was tranquil and beneficent like Lord Shiva Himself! A momentary smile flickered on his lips as he gave me a meaningful glance and then looked away.
>
> "You see the point of the miracle, don't you?"
>
> "That he was beyond nama-rupa?"
>
> "That's right," he answered reflectively. "Or shall I say: the One beyond all maya, the Star beyond the phantoms, the Last Reality beyond the ephemera, the Silence beyond the songs - you may make use of any simile you fancy. Personally, I look upon it as a sign of his Grace - his giving me the answer in a way only he could have given.
>
> I smiled. "So he met you more than halfway?"
>
> "He is compassion itself, don't you know?"
>
> "I do. But what then?"
>
> "The rest is silence," he answered. "Don't you know your Shakespeare?"

Reference: 1.Mahajan Samvad, Dr. Govindagopal Mukhopadhyaya,Prachi Publications, 2nd edition.

2. https://www.innerdirections.org/krishna-prem/
3. https://www.arunachala.org/newsletters/2006/jan-feb